# Selecting an instance if another instance doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in my database that has a columns called `name_type`. This can contain many 3 character combinations for each user.  So, user 123 can have 'PRF', 'PRI', 'USA', 'BRA' etc.

There is a single row for each instance of `name_type`.

So, I might have the following...

```
emplid  Name_type
123     PRF
123     PRI
```

I want to display the row for each `emplid` that has a 'PRF' name type.  If an `emplid` does not have a 'PRF' name type, then I want to display the row relating to the 'PRI' name type. When they have both, I want it to default to 'PRF'.  If it helps, EVERY `emplid` will have a 'PRI' row.

This is something I could write in 6 languages using if statements but, trying to figure it out using AND and OR statements and subqueries, has just been a nightmare.

How can I do this in SQL?

*edit... here is the current code with some of the names adjusted.  This does not include the PRF portion.

```
select a.emplid 
, b.national_id 
, a.name 
, a.last_name_srch 
, a.first_name_srch 
, 'xxxxx' || substr(b.national_id 
,6 
,4) 
, c.birthdate 
from qr_names a 
, qr_pers_nid b 
, qr_person c 
where a.emplid = b.emplid 
and a.emplid = c.emplid 
and b.country = ( 
select max(b1.country) 
from qr_pers_nid b1 
where b1.emplid = b.emplid) 
and a.name_type ='pri' 
and a.effdt = ( 
select max(a1.effdt) 
from qr_names a1 
where a1.emplid = a.emplid 
and a1.name_type = a.name_type);
```

Comment: Please review [How to write a good SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info0. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for either value (with `IN`, or if you prefer with `OR`) which will give you one or two rows for each ID; and then use aggregation to keep the lower value:

```
select emplid, min(name_type) as name_type
from your_table
where name_type in ('PRF', 'PRI')
group by emplid
order by emplid;
```

... which works here because the string 'PRF' will sort alphabetically before the string 'PRI'.

Slightly more generically you can explicitly specify the ranking to determine which value to keep:

```
select emplid,
  min(name_type) keep (dense_rank first order by 
    case name_type when 'PRF' then 1 when 'PRI' then 2 end) as name_type
from your_table
where name_type in ('PRF', 'PRI')
group by emplid
order by emplid;
```

The `order by` clause within the `keep` is using a case expression to assign a numeric value to each option, and then the first of those is kept. (It doesn't matter what the case expression evaluates to - I've happened to use 1 and 2, but they could be 'A' and 'B', or anything - as long as those values will always be sorted in the order you need, so 'PRF' will be ranked before 'PRI'.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uAZzX8qi)

That would also extend to searching for more than two values, and would make it easy to apply whatever sort criteria to want between the values - so if you wanted to find, in order of precedence, say PRF, USA, PRI then you would just rank then in that order.

If your table has other columns that you also want to retrieve then you can do apply the same `min() keep ()` mechasim to the other columns, but that would get tedious; so instead you could do the ranking in a subquery, using the same case expression, and then filter the results:

```
select emplid, name_type, other
from (
  select emplid, name_type, other, -- whatever columns you need to retrieve
    dense_rank() over (partition by emplid order by 
      case name_type when 'PRF' then 1 when 'PRI' then 2 end) as rnk
  from your_table
  where name_type in ('PRF', 'PRI')
)
where rnk = 1
order by emplid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FdOCU3PV)

---

Applied to your sample code, that might look like:

```
select emplid, national_id, name, last_name_srch, first_name_srch,
  xxx, birthdate
from (
  -- your original query now as a subquery...
  select a.emplid 
  , b.national_id 
  , a.name 
  , a.last_name_srch 
  , a.first_name_srch 
  , 'xxxxx' || substr(b.national_id 
  ,6 
  ,4) as xxx -- added alias to refer to later
  , c.birthdate 
  -- plus new ranking expression...
  , dense_rank() over (partition by emplid order by 
      case name_type when 'prf' then 1 when 'pri' then 2 end) as rnk
  from qr_names a 
  , qr_pers_nid b 
  , qr_person c 
  where a.emplid = b.emplid 
  and a.emplid = c.emplid 
  and b.country = ( 
    select max(b1.country) 
    from qr_pers_nid b1 
    where b1.emplid = b.emplid) 
  -- check for both values here
  -- and a.name_type ='pri' 
  and a.name_type in ('pri', 'prf') 
  and a.effdt = ( 
    select max(a1.effdt) 
    from qr_names a1 
    where a1.emplid = a.emplid 
    and a1.name_type = a.name_type)
  -- end of your query
)
where rnk = 1;
```

(You might want to look at modern join syntax; and you could get the country and effective date with joins and similar ranking instead of subqueries - that's all incidental though...)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think seeing my code formatting may assist in this issue.  I've edited the post to give an example.  In mine, I'm not actually using name_type as a part of the select, just as a parameter in the query.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't really matter if you use the second subquery approach - you can just make your current query the subquery, adding the rank expression; change `and a.name_type ='pri'` to `and a.name_type in ('pri', 'prf`)`; and then filter on the rank?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying so, take this response with a grain of salt.  If you have 2 rows attached to your ID... 1 is 'pri' and the other is 'prf'.  We want to display the row associated with 'prf'.  We do NOT want to show the row with 'pri'.  If you do NOT have a 'prf' row, we want to show your 'pri' row.  So, you setting a 'rank' = 1 is only going to give me the 'prf'.  But, since not everyone has 'prf', it's going to miss those with a 'pri' and no 'prf'.

Comment: @Ashley - no, in that case the 'pri' row will have rank 1. The fiddle I linked to has an ID with just PRI, one with just PRF, and one with both - and they each return one row. I think what might be confusing you is that the case expression evaluates to 1 or 2, but it could equally evaluate to 99 and 100, or A and B, or today and tomorrow; it doesn't matter, it's the *order* of that value among all the rows for the ID that forms the rank. There will always be a row ranked first, by definition; there may be a row ranked second. (And I've updated the answer with your code modified...)

Comment: Alex, your answer worked!  Sorry for the delay in letting you know.  Thanks for your help!!!   Ashley